# How to list all existing users using Riak admin-shell?

Tags: riak

In Riak, how do I retrieve a list of currently existing users? I can't seem to find it anywhere on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This info can be accessed at any time:

> ```
> riak-admin security print-users
> ```
>
> Example output, assuming user named `riakuser` with an assigned password:
>
> ```
> +----------+--------+----------------------+------------------------------+
> | username | groups |       password       |           options            |
> +----------+--------+----------------------+------------------------------+
> | riakuser |        |983e8ae1421574b8733824|              []              |
> +----------+--------+----------------------+------------------------------+
> ```
>
> Note: All passwords are displayed in encrypted form in console output.
>
> If you’d like to see which permissions have been assigned to `riakuser`, you would need to use the `print-grants` command.
>
> The `security print-user` (singular) command can be used with a name as argument to see the same information as above, except for only that user.

See basho/docs [Security Basics](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/using/security/basics/) for more information on user management.